# What is the safe fill limit of XFS partition?

Tags: storage, xfs

Recently i purchased couple of 4TB drives with the intent of archiving camera footage on them. Naturally, I'd like to jam as much data on the two drives as i can. Once the partition is full, it should almost never be written, basically the files will just sit there and be read.

Hypothetically if i fill the whole partition leaving couple of gigs of free space, will there be any detrimental effects to the data integrity, or read speed? And if so, what is the theoretical minimum free space required to avoid such problems.

PS:

I opted out of using LVM and spanning single partition across multiple physical drives out of fear of drive failure taking the whole thing down.

My budget does not permit mirrored raid setup. for the time being, I am stuck with JBOD storage scheme.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data integrity is not affected in any way by fragmentation, which is the only possible drawback of overfilling a partition.

If you don't update or remove any files, then you will not have any fragmentation and can therefore fill the partition completely.